# Extract value from class 'requests_html.Element'

Tags: python, python-requests

I have succesfully sent a request to a website using a selector using

```
request.html.find(#selector(.
```

This returns a list array of length 1, which I can then extract from the list using `offernew[0]`, where offernew is what is returned after the `html.find` query.

This returns something of type `<class 'requests_html.Element'>`, and contains

```
 <Element 'input' type='hidden' name='ThisIsWhatIWant' value='XXXXXYYYY'>
```

I am trying to extract the `ThisIsWhatIWant` value, however I am really stuck. As far as I can see this value cannot be extracted like a dictionary or list, so could anyone please advise?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what module do you use ? Different modules may use different function  `.get("name")` or `["name"]` or `.attr("name")` or `.attrib("name")`, etc. You should simply read documentation.

Comment: Hi, I am using for this requests_html. I have thoroughly read the documentation, but I have not got anywhere with it and am really struggling to understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: I checked documentation for [requests_html](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) and on first page I see example `Introspect an Element’s attributes: >>> about.attrs` and this is your answer `.attrs['name']` - ie. `html.find(...)[0].attrs{'name']`

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for [requests_html](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) on first page shows

```
Introspect an Element’s attributes: 
>>> about.attrs 
{'id': 'about', 'class': ('tier-1', 'element-1'), 'aria-haspopup': 'true'}
```

and this is your answer

```
html.find(...)[0].attrs{'name']
```

---

Minimal working code with real URL created specially for learning

```
import requests_html

s = requests_html.HTMLSession()
r = s.get('http://books.toscrape.com/')

for item in r.html.find('h3 a'):
    print('title:', item.attrs['title'])
```